# Сравнение строк

Tags: c#

В результате выполнения вода:

```
string str1="any text";
string str2="any text";
bool equal=(str1==str2);
```

Значение переменной "equal" всегда будет истинно или в C#, как и Java, строки сравниваются по ссылке? **Заранее спасибо.**

*P.S.1: Проверить компилятором не могу. Из Джавы знаю, что строки кешируються и среда выполнения часто автоматически вешает ссылки на один и тот же объект при создании двух и более строк с одинаковым содержимым.

P.S.2: Гуглил, на большинстве ресурсов пишут одно, а на других - противоположное, хз кому верить.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так:

```
string str1="any text";
string str2="any text";
bool equal=(str1==str2);//True
bool equal1 = str1.Equals(str2);//True
str2="another text";
equal=(str1==str2);//False
equal1 = str1.Equals(str2);//False
```

по идеи у класса String есть перегрузка оператора `==`, которая неявно выполняет метод `Equals`, но я могу ошибаться